# Angular js service returns function objects when called from a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

```
var newservices = angular.module('newservices', []);
newservices.service('newservice', function ($http) {
return{
newdata: function(parameter){
            return $http.get('/devicedetails/'+parameter).success(function(data)        {
                console.log(data)
                return data

            });

},
}
});
```

The above service is included in one of my controllers

```
data=newService.newdata($scope.dummy)
console.log(data)
```

while trying to print data what i  get is $http function object as shown below

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function, success: function, error: function}
```

why is this so??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is not an error. It's a Promise.
You did an `$http` GET request, which is asynchronous. `$http.get`returns a promise that will be resolved when the remote request is completed. In that moment, you'll get the final value.

See this example, where `getShops` would be your method `newData`

```
 this.getShop = function (id, lang) {
    var promise = $http.get(appRoot + 'model/shops_' + lang + '.json');
    return promise;
 };
```

In a controller you can use it like this:

```
   Shops.getShop($routeParams.id).then(function (response) {
       console.log("data is", response.data);
       $scope.shop = response.data[$routeParams.id];
   });
```

When the data is ready, assign it to a scope.

In your case:

```
var data;
newService.newdata($scope.dummy).then(function (response) {
   data = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your service is returnig a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q)

You should use some what like this, not tested though it should work.

```
data = newService.newdata($scope.dummy).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                },       
                function (error) {
                        return error;
                 });
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is the best practice to use promise under all circumstances even if the operation is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong.

This work in promises. so in you controller you need to consume the promisses.

```
newService.newData($scope.dummy)
  .then(function (data){
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Try this.

Comment: Ya this ofcourse works.I am trying to directly access data from the service.My  method in question works when used along with a resolve function.